# telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The Server returned HTTP 409 conflict

Tags: python, api, telegram

A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful and produced the following error.

```
 telebot.apihelper.ApiException A request to the Telegram API was 
 unsuccessful. The Server returned HTTP 409 conflict
 Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. 
 Response body:
 [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict:  
 terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot 
 instance is running"}']

 ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 
 The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict.           
 Response body:
 [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates 
 request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}']"
 (util.py:65 Polling Thread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, 
 args=('A request   to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned    
 HTTP 409 Conflict. 
 Response body:
 \n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates 
  request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}\']',)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can only use one instance of getUpdates

Comment: Can you explain where i can change in the code

Comment: You're probably running the bot in two different instances and they are conficting each other.

Comment: Actually i made a bot from bot father on telegram. There is only one bot i have created.

Comment: I was talking about the script you're running. the error is saying that you have two scripts running.

Comment: No . actually there is one only main file where the whole code  has written

Comment: Please share your code, and how you've started the script. I guess it's still running in the background

Comment: I use this link to try to access to my bot: https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getUpdates:
then I got this one :
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":1032572032,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"Rest_Bot","username":"rest_chatbot","can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":false,"supports_inline_queries":true}}